# Phone Gimbal - complete rotation lock in space

Tags: cameraphones

I'm new to topic of gimbals. I'm trying to accomplish following scenario: I have a phone, and I want to keep its camera always facing ceiling (parallelly) and always in same rotation in respect to xy coordinates.

To illustrate this:
While I move (and rotate) with phone from point A -> B -> C, I want it to have always the very same xyz rotation.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this with commercial phone gimbals? If yes, for which features in specifications should I look for to know gimbal is capable of it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! I think it's a good question. I'm curious though, *why* do you want to have the camera always pointing at the ceiling? I'm asking this, as there is perhaps another way to achieve your goal (if we know what the goal is).

Comment: Is it for photo or video? For photo you would just need a triangle.